# PDO issues with binding IN operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Note: I see this question as a probable **serious issue in PDO Drivers**. I can pretty much understand the difference between an array and string. So, please consider testing this on your sandbox before **Deleting** or making **[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)**.

```
$pdo = db()->getInstance();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN :clients";
$params = [ ":clients" =>  "(223,224,225)" ];    

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
try{
    $stmt->execute($params);
} catch( \Exception $e){
    die("Query Execution Failed" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

> Query Execution FailedSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''(223,224,225)'' at line 1

The issue here is instead of translating to:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN (223,224,225)
```

it is translating to:

```
 SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN '(223,224,225)'
```

There are no arrays here. I am just providing a parameter clients to replace `:clients`. **Why does it add the `quotes` around?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: just create a dynamic placeholder which corresponds to the number of inputs, them load em all up in the `->execute()`, just check the link above given in the comments section

Comment: . Either check above link or do like :- `$params = [ ":clients" =>  "("."223".","."224".","."225".")" ];`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta. I know that. But, I am not passing array. I am passing string that needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Ghost, I checked that answer. It's not my issue.

Comment: @A-2-A, Am I not passing the same thing?

Comment: It is **your issue**. Explode your string and work with array of values.

Comment: @u_mulder, I already have exploded it before passing, sweetheart.

Comment: I don't see anything exploded in your code, sweetheart.

Comment: @u_mulder The output of explode is string. I already have a ready string **with quotes**.

Comment: And you should explode this string to get array of values - `[223, 224,225]`. And then check a linked answer. That's all.

Comment: @u_mulder, If you think that works, why don't you post an answer that works?

Comment: Answer is already posted in a first comment.

Comment: The answer linked is precisely the solution you need. Why don't you give it a try instead of hanging on to a self-entitled attitude and insist on being spoon-fed an answer?

Comment: its not serious issue in PDO Drivers. you are doing some thing wrong. the above comments are enough to solve your problem.

Comment: All you need to understand is that [placeholder have to represent a complete data literal only](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in) - a string or a number namely. And thus it is impossible to substitute just an arbitrary query part with a placeholder. Hope it will clear your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I agree with you (somewhat). It's a issue, not very serious one. Maybe they kept it knowingly. Or, maybe your stupid question has some debate potentials.

> Every PDO parameter gets wrapped with quotes. (Personally I think should not be). When you pass the `IN` string at once, it puts quote around it which fails the query. But, you can do that (put quotes) with individual item. So, **pass parameter to each item instead of preparing string before.**

Now, to the solution:

```
$pdo = db()->getInstance();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN :clients";

$clients = [223,224,225];

/* You could use bind with ? here. I am just making this with named parameters so that you could echo SQL */

$params = [];
$replacement = [];

foreach ($clients as $key => $value){
    $replacement[] = ":client$key";
    $params[":client" . $key] = $value;
}
$sql = str_replace(":clients", "("  . implode(",",$replacement) . ")", $sql);

echo $sql;
/* SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN (:client0,:client1,:client2) */

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
try{
    $stmt->execute($params);
    print_pre($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} catch( \Exception $e){
    die("Query Execution Failed" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

This works like a charm. I tried by creating a dummy clients table. But the thing is your actual SQL now becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN ('223','224','225')
```

Most people might not give a shit about it but you might lose some performance because the query is  **converting the id to string with quotes**, especially you have a large database, complex queries and prefer integers.

Comment: Please, don't call an SQL syntax error on the user side a "PDO issue". Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your fears about casting, mysql is smart enough to cast query parameters only once.

Comment: By the way, you you should never catch errors to report them.